# javascript how to split a string in multiple arrays after specific character

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I am trying to split (in Vanilla JS) a string into a single or multiple arrays after each \n character.

For example :

```
let string = '1 2 3 4\n5 6 7 8\n9 8 7 6';
```

should return :

```
let combinedArrays = [[1, 2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8],[9, 8, 7, 6]];
```

by splitting the let string after every \n character and deleting all the space characters.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Using split js function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let combinedArrays = string.split('\n').map(el => el.split(' '))
```

```js
let string = '1 2 3 4\n5 6 7 8\n9 8 7 6';
console.log(string.split('\n').map(el => el.split(' ')))
```

Please read more about `split()` method here: https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: Thanks. How the element el could be a Number(el) ?

Comment: Almost! You should use one more `map` operator. `string.split('\n').map(el => el.split(' ').map(n => Number(n)))`
Please mark my answer liker correct)